SqlPackage.exe not honoring DoNotDropObjectTypes
When deploying Sql Server changes, I'm seeing objects being dropped despite requesting them not to be dropped. For example, in /p:DoNotDropObjectTypes, I specified Services, but in the deployment output, it fails while attempting to drop the Services that exist.
What am I doing wrong?
Here's the pipeline task:
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: Deploy Azure SQL Db
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
    authenticationType: servicePrincipal
    serverName: ${{ parameters.sqlServerName }}
    databaseName: ${{ parameters.sqlDatabaseName }}
    DacpacFile: ${{ parameters.dacpacFile }}
    AdditionalArguments: |
        /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=True
        /p:DropObjectsNotInSource=True
        /p:DoNotDropObjectTypes=Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions;Credentials;DatabaseScopedCredentials;LinkedServerLogins;LinkedServers;Services;MessageTypes;
        /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False

Here's the deployment failing while trying to drop a Service:
Could not deploy package.
Warning SQL72032: If this deployment is executed, [dbo_t1_xxxxx_Receiver] will be dropped and not re-created.
Warning SQL72032: If this deployment is executed, [dbo_t2_xxxxx_Receiver] will be dropped and not re-created.
Warning SQL72032: If this deployment is executed, [dbo_t3_xxxxx_Receiver] will be dropped and not re-created.
Warning SQL72032: If this deployment is executed, [dbo_t4_xxxxx_Receiver] will be dropped and not re-created.
Warning SQL72032: If this deployment is executed, [dbo_t5_xxxxx_Receiver] will be dropped and not re-created.
Warning SQL72032: If this deployment is executed, [dbo_t1_xxxxx_Sender] will be dropped and not re-created.
Warning SQL72032: If this deployment is executed, [dbo_t2_xxxxx_Sender] will be dropped and not re-created.
Warning SQL72032: If this deployment is executed, [dbo_t3_xxxxx_Sender] will be dropped and not re-created.
Warning SQL72032: If this deployment is executed, [dbo_t4_xxxxx_Sender] will be dropped and not re-created.
Warning SQL72032: If this deployment is executed, [dbo_t5_xxxxx_Sender] will be dropped and not re-created.
Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
Cannot drop the service 'dbo_t4_xxxxx_Sender', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
DROP SERVICE [dbo_t4_xxxxx_Sender];
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1.
Finishing: Deploy Azure SQL Db

